# How to import Osmosis DB schemas into PostGIS DB

Tags: postgis, osmosis

I'm trying to import `Osmosis` schema into into a `PostGIS` DB. I followed this [article](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage).

I created a DB:

```
createdb osm_schema
```

Then I executed the following command:

```
osmosis --write-pgsql host="localhost" database="osm_schema" pgsimple_schema_0.6.sql
```

`pgsimple_schema_0.6.sql`  is the basic schema I found in `Osmosis` tarball inside Script directory.
The command above fails to execute. I got the following error:

> Nov 16, 2012 6:51:39 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
>   INFO: Osmosis Version 0.40.1 Nov 16, 2012 6:51:41 PM
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run INFO: Preparing pipeline.
>   Nov 16, 2012 6:51:41 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
>   SEVERE: Execution aborted.
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: No default
>   pipes are available as input for task 1-write-pgsql.  at
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.PipeTasks.retrieveTask(PipeTasks.java:150)
>     at
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.TaskManager.getInputTask(TaskManager.java:165)
>     at
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.v0_6.SinkManager.connect(SinkManager.java:50)
>     at
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.connectTasks(Pipeline.java:74)
>     at
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.prepare(Pipeline.java:116)
>     at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:86)  at
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:328)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:408)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:351)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Use psql to execute SQL scripts that generate schemas.

You don't need osmosis to generate OSM schemas. Osmosis reads and writes from files and databases, but it does not create schamas.

There's a detailed [WIKI page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/PostGIS_Setup) on how to create the OSM schema and import OSM data using osmosis.